# pandas: Add row from one data frame to another data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes with identical column headers.

I am iterating over the rows in df1, splitting one of the columns, and then using those split columns to create multiple rows to add to the other dataframe.

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    curr_awards = row['AWARD'].split(" ")
    for award in curr_awards:
        new_line = row
        new_line['AWARD'] = award.strip()
        #insert code here to add new_line to df2
```

What is the pandas method for adding a row to another data frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    curr_awards = row['AWARD'].split(" ")
    for award in curr_awards:
        new_line = row
        new_line['AWARD'] = award.strip()
        df2.loc[len(df2)] = new_line
```