# Adding a row from one data frame to the top of another, python

Tags: row, jupyter-notebook, concatenation

I am working in Jupyter Notebook (in python). I have two dataframes that are csv files, titled df1970 and df1966. I would like to take the FIRST row of the data frame 1970 and add it to the top of df1966. 
I tried looking at this question ([pandas: Add row from one data frame to another data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030164/pandas-add-row-from-one-data-frame-to-another-data-frame)), but I am not sure which are the columns in the question, which are rows, and which are data.

So, for mine, I tried the following code.

```
songinQ = df1970.iloc[[0]]

verticalStack = pd.concat([df1966, songinQ], axis=0)
verticalStack
```

However, this adds "songinQ" to the bottom. *I want it to be at the top*.

Comment: The reason for extra columns to the right is probably due to mis-matching of column names between the two data frames. You can try to rename them so that df1966 and songinQ have the same column names, then switch the order of concat so that songinQ goes on top.

Comment: Thank you; fixing the columns to match did get rid of the added columns to the right of the original dataframe. However, it doesn't add it to the top. The "songinQ" (which is the one row of the df1970 dataframe I wanted to extract, is still at the bottom. (see italicized text in edited Question).

Comment: Did you try `pd.concat([songinQ, df1966], axis=0)`?

Comment: Worked! The order of songinQ and df1966 matter. Thank you.